# Categorical duals for finitely-generated projective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

For a not necessarily commutative ring $R$, its category of bimodules $_BMod_B$ has a monoidal structure given by $\otimes_R$. Consider now an object $M$ in the subcategory whose objects are finitely-generated projective as left modules. Will $Hom(M,R)$, the bimodule of left $R$-module maps be a left dual for $M$ in$_BMod_B$, ?

Comment: How do you define the tensor product over $R$ of two left modules when $R$ is not commutative ?

Comment: You mean that if you want $M \otimes_R N$ for $M,N$ two left modules, you put the trivial right $R$-module structure on $M$ ?

Comment: No, I am looking at two bimodules, both of which are assumed to be fgp as left modules.

Comment: Ok sorry for the misunderstanding ! have you seen this MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339262/dual-of-a-bimodule post and the blog post it links to https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/dualizable-objects-and-morphisms/ ?

Comment: Since things are flipped around when $A$ is not commutative, I think that taking duals get you out of the subcategory of fpg left modules. Also if you want the tensor product $M\otimes_R N$ to be a left fpg module, maybe you need $M$ to be fpg right.

Comment: Yes, that seems to make sense . . . I have reworded the question. Thanks!

Comment: Now there are consitency problems in your question, you have some $R$ lefts when you changed tyhings for $B$ also you should ask for the left or right handedness of the dual !

Comment: So I have asked for a left dual, which should fix things.

Answer (score 0):

According to Etingof et al:

> [Exercise 1.10.16] Let $A$ be an algebra. Show that $M \in A$-bimod has a left (respectively,right) dual if and only if it is finitely generated projective when considered as  a left (respectively,right) A-module.

So it seems a dual basis argument settles the question.

Comment: Yes, and the argument is written down in details in this blog post at the dualizable bimodules section : https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/dualizable-objects-and-morphisms/